# Why in my tkinter calculator GUI after the execution an = sign gets added?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator

I just made a simple calculator GUI using tkinter module after writing the code i get the following bug:

Whenever I am executing an = sign gets added after every evalution.PLease check as to why an = sign gets added everytime. PLease tell me how to debug my calculator GUI .

Example :
Like if i am evaluating ( 5 ** 2) , instead of 25 the answer i get is 25= .

```
root = Tk()

root.title('Calculator BY SATYAM')

def click(event):
    global string
    text = event.widget.cget('text')
    if text == '=':
        if string.get().isdigit():
            value = int (string.get())
        else :
            try:
                value = eval(string.get())


            except Exception as e:
                value = 'Error'

        string.set(value)
        screen.update()
    if text == 'C':
        string.set(' ')
        screen.update()
    else:
        string.set(string.get()+text)
        screen.update()



string = StringVar()

screen = Entry(root,textvariable = string , font = 'General 40 bold italic')
screen.pack( fill = X)

f = Frame(root,bg = 'grey')

Button1 = Button(f,text = "1" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button1.bind('<Button-1>',click)


Button2 = Button(f,text = "2" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw', fill = BOTH)
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',click)



Button3 = Button(f,text = "3" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button3.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button3.bind('<Button-1>',click)

f.pack( )

f = Frame(root,bg = 'grey')

Button1 = Button(f,text = "4" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button1.bind('<Button-1>',click)


Button2 = Button(f,text = "5" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw', fill = BOTH)
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',click)



Button3 = Button(f,text = "6" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button3.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button3.bind('<Button-1>',click)

f.pack()




f = Frame(root,bg = 'grey')

Button1 = Button(f,text = "7" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button1.bind('<Button-1>',click)


Button2 = Button(f,text = "8" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw', fill = BOTH)
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',click)



Button3 = Button(f,text = "9" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button3.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button3.bind('<Button-1>',click)

f.pack()


f = Frame(root,bg = 'grey')

Button1 = Button(f,text = "=" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button1.bind('<Button-1>',click)


Button2 = Button(f,text = "C" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw', fill = BOTH)
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',click)



Button3 = Button(f,text = "**" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button3.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button3.bind('<Button-1>',click)

f.pack()


f = Frame(root,bg = 'grey')

Button1 = Button(f,text = "+" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button1.bind('<Button-1>',click)


Button2 = Button(f,text = "-" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw', fill = BOTH)
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',click)



Button3 = Button(f,text = "*" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button3.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button3.bind('<Button-1>',click)

f.pack()


f = Frame(root,bg = 'grey')

Button1 = Button(f,text = "/" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button1.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button1.bind('<Button-1>',click)


Button2 = Button(f,text = "//" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button2.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw', fill = BOTH)
Button2.bind('<Button-1>',click)



Button3 = Button(f,text = "00" , bg = "grey" , bd = 2,fg = 'WHite' , font = 'General 30 bold',height = 5 , width = 7)
Button3.pack(side = LEFT , anchor = 'nw' , fill = BOTH)
Button3.bind('<Button-1>',click)

f.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `if text == "C"` to `elif text == "C"`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `click` function, you have the following if-conditions:

```
    if text == '=':

    ...

    if text == 'C':
        string.set(' ')
        screen.update()
    else:
        string.set(string.get()+text)
        screen.update()
```

Note that these if conditions are at the same level of indentation. Thus, the first if-condition is evaluated. *No matter* whether the first one is true or false, the second one also gets evaluated. If `text` equals `'='`, the `else` clause of that second if statement is entered, and the text (thus, '='), is added to the current string.

You'll need to make an exception if you don't want to add the '=' sign to that second loop. For example:

```
    if text == 'C':
        string.set(' ')
        screen.update()
    elif text != '=':
        string.set(string.get()+text)
        screen.update()
    else:  # This else clause may not be necessary
        screen.update()
```

Alternatively, you can make a section of `if-elif-elif-else` clauses:

```
    if text == '=':
    ...
    elif text == 'C':
    ...
    elif text == 'something else':
    ...
    else:
        string.set(string.get()+text)
        screen.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're not using it in a good way..
the click() function must be this:

```py
def click(event):
    global string
    text = event.widget.cget('text')
    if text == '=':
        if string.get().isdigit():
            value = int (string.get())
        else :
            try:
                value = eval(string.get())


            except Exception as e:
                value = 'Error'

        string.set(value)
        screen.update()
    elif text == 'C':
        string.set(' ')
        screen.update()
    else:
        string.set(string.get()+text)
        screen.update()
```

as the lines are if-if-else and not if-elif-else..

it works like this:

```
> if text is "=":
  yes it is "="
     evaluate..
end this conditon..
> if text is "C":
  no, "=" is not "C"..
    goto else..
> else:
  as "=" is not "C", add "=" to the the entry..
```